# Spring Boot 2.0.0: HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Я получил ошибку:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Мой код:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).
        withCatalogName(packageName).
        withProcedureName(procedureName);

Map<String, Object> sqlParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(RMSEntityParam entityParam: entity.getParams()) {
    jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(entityParam.getName(), OracleTypes.ARRAY, entityParam.getType().name()));
    sqlParams.put(entityParam.getName(), new SqlArrayValue<>(new Object[]{entityParam.getValue()}));
}

jdbcCall.execute(sqlParams);
```

Я знаю, что можно преобразовать Хикари-коннекшен к оракловому, как рекомендуют здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087536/hikaricp-pass-oracle-custom-type

но конструктор SimpleJdbcCall может принимать на вход только JdbcTemplate или DataSource.

Hikari Version: 2.8.0
SpringBoot: 2.0.0

Как я могу решить проблему с Хикари?

P.S.: Переходить на CallableStatement не планирую.
Проблема возникла при переходе со Спринг Бут 1.5.9 на версию 2.0.0.
Раньше всё отрабатывало корректно.

P.S.S.: Вероятнее всего, проблема возникает из-за передачи кастомного типа ораклового массива. Но в предыдущей версии спринга ошибки не было. Откатываться не планирую.

Comment: Перевёл на русский.

Comment: та же проблемма